# Help with natural deduction (Propositional logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm trying to get to $(\neg A \to C)$ from the following formula: 
$$(A \wedge B) \vee (\neg A \wedge C)$$

I have attempted the following:
    $$((A \wedge B) \vee \neg A) \wedge ((A \wedge B) \vee C ) \text{  distribution}$$ 
    $$((A \wedge B) \vee C) \wedge ((A \wedge B) \vee \neg A) \text{ commutation}$$
    $$(A \wedge B) \vee C                   \text{  simplification}$$
   $$(C \vee (A \wedge B)                \text{  commutation}$$
    $$(C \vee A) \wedge (C \vee B)              \text{  distribution}$$
    $$(C \vee A)                          \text{  simplification}$$

I'm stuck from this point, I have no idea how to change the $A$ into a $\neg A$ and would love some help solving this.

Comment: $A \vee C$ is the same as $\neg A \rightarrow C$.

Comment: Yeah, see this notion of material implication : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29

Comment: @mrp I swapped (C V A) into (A V C) using commutation and then tried ¬A→C using the Def. of Implication law but the online testing system that my school provides says that the specified formula can not be deduced by that so I was wondering if there was any other way?

Comment: Since there are several ways of solving the problem, and various "starting points" you could be starting at, it would be helpful to know what you're allowed to use and what you aren't. So, what is the list of transformations your online testing system will allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that when using the **[natural deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction)** method, we do not primarily operate with algebraic rules such as *association*, *commutation, distribution* or *simplification*. Instead, we set for each one of the logical connectives a pair of **introduction** and **elimination rules**. Algebraic properties such as associativity, commutativity  and so on of a connective, if exist, can be deduced from those rules, and they are known as **derivate rules**.

---

Now the statement you want to prove is the following:

**Proposition:**

$$(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C) \vdash (¬A→C)$$

**Proof**:

I provide below a formal proof in the terms I described above:

> 1. $(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C)$, premise
>
> > 2. $\neg A$, assumption
> >
> >    > 3. $(\neg A \land C)$, assumption
> >    > 4. $C$, 3, $\land$-elimination
> > 3. $(\neg A \land C) \rightarrow C$, 3-4, $\rightarrow$-introduction
> >
> > > 6. $(A∧B)$, assumption
> > > 7. $A$, 6, $\land$-elimination
> > > 8. $\bot$, 2,6, $\land$-introduction //$A\land \neg A$
> > > 9. $C$, 3, *ex falsum*
> >
> > 10. $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$, 6-9, $\rightarrow$-introduction
> > 11. $C$, 1,3,10, $\lor$-elimination
>
> 12. $(¬A→C)$, 2-11, $\rightarrow$-introduction

Comment: @Mauro Thanks, my lack of attention. The second line 3 (supposed to be the step 5) seems to be a MathJax problem though, I simply can't get '5' wrote down in it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use disjunction elimination on $(C \lor A)$.

Longer answer: Assume $¬A$.  Since you have $(C \lor A)$, that means if you assume $A$, that you'll get a contradiction.  So, you can get $(A → C)$.  Get $(C → C)$.  Then use disjunction elimination to get to $C$.  Then discharge the hypothesis $¬A$ into the conditional ($¬A$ → C) and you have the result.

Comment: But the OP's question ask to derive $(¬A→C)$, which is equivalent to $A \lor C$... Thus, we "have not" $(C∨A)$.